# Different Front page for Mobile

Tags: options, mobile, frontpage

I want to make a different front-page and show it to the mobile user, instead of the one used on desktop.

In detail, right now we have set our site to show desktop-front-page to user, when he lands on www.domain.com. Now, I want to make a different front-page (mobile-front-page) which can be served to the user coming from mobile. Is that possible? Any ideas?

PS. I looked into `wp_is_mobile()` but that seems to send mobile user to a URL you specify. What I actually need is that user should land (and remain) on www.domain.com, but instead of the desktop-front-page, the mobile-front-page should be served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the actual template file could work in the same way as above using `get_template_part()`.

For example...

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { // If it is a mobile device

get_template_part( 'mobile-front', 'page' );

} else { // If it is not a mobile device

get_template_part( 'desktop-front', 'page' );

} // end wp_is_mobile()
```

To take this a step further...

You could add a filter on `template_include` to load the specific template file using `wp_is_mobile()` to determine which template file to load.

[The Codex info for `template_include`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're on the right track with `wp_is_mobile()`.

Have you tried creating just one front-page.php and adding an if / else statement to alter display between desktop and mobile?

Something like:

```
 <?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { // If it is a mobile device

get_header( 'mobile' );
// Display some other stuff here
get_footer( 'mobile' );

} else { // If it is not a mobile device

get_header();
// Display some other stuff here
get_footer();

} // end wp_is_mobile()
```

Comment: Sweet. This could surely be one way. I will wait for someone to chip-in with the method where I can switch front-pages, if not I will mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be off as this is an old question but I have found [this](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/137760/can-i-set-my-homepage-to-a-different-page-for-mobi.html) answer here and it works, it simply redirects the main page to the mobile home page using this script in the home page text editor where /mobile is the link you want to redirect to. I have tried it and it works you can check it on [medicalfa](https://medicalfa.gr).

```
<script>
 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <760) {
   window.location = "/mobile";
 }
 </script>
```